# Python dictionary becomes empty as soon as the function, which added items to it, finishes execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

I am trying to write a menu in which option 1 would add a key:value pair to a dictionary and option 2 would run a threading module using the items from the dictionary. Key is a message from the user input and Value is a number of seconds, from the user input, that a thread should pause for, before displaying the message.

Threading itself is irrelevant right now though. What I'm struggling with is the fact that when I use the function for option 1, it adds the key:value pairs to the dictionary (called messages_and_times) successfully. But as soon as the function is finished the dictionary becomes empty again, as can be seen from the function for option 2, which accesses it.

At the bottom you can see my code. I've added the following lines in order to check what's in the dictionary at each step:

```
    print(dict(messages_and_times))
    if not messages_and_times:
        print("This dictionary is empty.")
    else:
        print("This dictionary contains items.")
```

It doesn't seem to work correctly either however. First of all it prints "This dictionary contains items." whether the printed dictionary looks empty or not. Second of all the following part of my code (clear() is used for clearing the terminal display):

```
def create_dictionary():
    clear()
    answer = input(
        "Would you like to add another message? (yes/no)").lower()
    if answer == "yes":
        option_1()
    elif answer == "no":
        clear()
        print("You will now be returned to the main menu.")    

        print(dict(messages_and_times))
```

does print a dictionary containing items if I chose to add them. But if I add the line

```
print(dict(messages_and_times))
```

to the main_menu() itself, the above mentioned create_dictionary() function prints an empty dictionary instead. Just this one print() statement in the main_menu() affects whether create_dictionary() shows a dictionary with items in it or not.

Could someone please help me understand how to design a code in which the dictionary retains the items created by one function, so that they can be accessed by other functions?

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance,

```
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
```

def main_menu():

```
list_of_messages = []
list_of_times = []
messages_and_times = zip(list_of_messages, list_of_times)

def option_1():
    clear()
    list_of_messages.append(
        input("Please type in a message you would like to add to the list:"))
    clear()
    list_of_times.append(
        input("Please type in the time of delay for this message:"))

    def create_dictionary():
        clear()
        answer = input(
            "Would you like to add another message? (yes/no)").lower()
        if answer == "yes":
            option_1()
        elif answer == "no":
            clear()
            print("You will now be returned to the main menu.")    

            print(dict(messages_and_times))            
            if not messages_and_times:
                print("This dictionary is empty.")
            else:
                print("This dictionary contains items.")

            time.sleep(1.5)
            main_menu()
        else:
            clear()
            print("Please answer yes or no.")
            time.sleep(1.5)
            create_dictionary()
    create_dictionary()

def option_2():
    clear()

    print(dict(messages_and_times))
    if not messages_and_times:
        print("This dictionary is empty.")
    else:
        print("This dictionary contains items.")

    time.sleep(5)
    main_menu()


clear()
selection = 0
while selection == 0:
    print(("-" * 15) + "MAIN MENU" + ("-" * 15) + "\n")
    print("1: Input a message and a corresponding time of delay before its display.")
    print("2: Print your customized list of messages.")
    print("3: Generate a list of random messages with random delays.\n")

    selection = int(input(
        "Please select one of the options, by typing in the corresponding number:"))

    if selection == 1:
        option_1()
    elif selection == 2:
        option_2()                        
    elif selection == 3:
        clear()
        print("You've selected the third option.")
    else:
        clear()
        print("Please select from options 1 - 3.\n")
        time.sleep(1.5)
        main_menu()
```

Comment: `messages_and_times` *is not a `dict`*, it is a `zip` object. See: `messages_and_times = zip(list_of_messages, list_of_times)
`. `zip` objects can only be iterated over once.

Comment: Ahh I see. What would be another effective way of combining those two user inputs into a dictionary that I can iterate over multiple times?

Comment: ... actually create a dictionary. Again, you are simply creating a `zip` object, and then exhausting it. You *do* create a `dict` out of it, but you simply print it, then it gets immediately reclaimed because no references exist to it.

Comment: `messages_and_times = dict(zip(list_of_messages, list_of_times))`.

Comment: @ Bakuriu This one also seems to behave like zip did on its own, so it doesn't work. I've sorted it out though. The two user inputs are now assigned to variables 'message' and 'seconds', and are followed by the line 'messages_and_times[message] = seconds'. Lastly I've made messages_and_times a global variable, and it works for now. Thank you so much for putting me on the right track guys!